# How can I add photo to vCard using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, vcf-vcard

I want to add an image and more details to the contact vcard using JS.
it's like a business page when people see the page they can save my contact through id="save-btn", And I want to add more than Name, phone, email.

The code working fine, but I don't know how to add photo and other details to the vcard, Like company, job, location, and more.

```js
var saveBtn = document.getElementById("save-btn");

saveBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {

  // Get the contact information from the website
  var contact = {
    name: "John Smith",
    phone: "555-555-5555",
    email: "john@example.com"
  };
  
  // create a vcard file
  var vcard = "BEGIN:VCARD\nVERSION:4.0\nFN:" + contact.name + "\nTEL;TYPE=work,voice:" + contact.phone + "\nEMAIL:" + contact.email + "\nEND:VCARD";
  var blob = new Blob([vcard], {
    type: "text/vcard"
  });
  var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

  const newLink = document.createElement('a');
  newLink.download = contact.name + ".vcf";
  newLink.textContent = contact.name;
  newLink.href = url;

  newLink.click();
});
```

```html
<button id="save-btn">Save Contact</button>
```

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. Asking us to do it for you isn't appropriate. Please see [ask] and take the [tour], then revise to be more clear about the problem.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

In VCARD format, "PHOTO" parameter exists (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard).
You can add this parameter and an URL of your photo.

```
PHOTO;JPEG:http://example.com/photo.jpg
```

Photo data encoded in base64 can also be directly embedded in your VCARD.

```
PHOTO;JPEG;ENCODING=BASE64:[base64-data]
```